# SQL Server equivalent of Oracle multi-valued IN subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to sql server so I am really struggling to translate my oracle sql in this area.  Normally in oracle sql I would use two items in my "in" clause but I guess that may not work so well in sql server?

Here is my data:

---

### notes_table

```
a_id     |     idxno     |     note_text

1              0               text 1 for item b_id = 61
2              1               text 2 for item b_id = 61
3              0               text 1 for item b_id = 71
4              1               text 2 for item b_id = 71
5              2               text 3 for item b_id = 71
6              0               text 1 for item b_id = 81
7              0               text 1 for item b_id = 91
8              1               text 2 for item b_id = 91
```

### notes_bridge_table

```
a_id     |     b_id     

1              61       
2              61       
3              71       
4              71       
5              71       
6              81       
7              91       
8              91
```

(**Note:  I am not guaranteed that a max(a_id) is a max(idxno) from the notes_table)

### item_table

```
b_id     |     item_desc
61             desc of item 61
71             desc of item 71
81             desc of item 81
91             desc of item 91
```

My desire is to display a report of the items with the greatest note from the notes table.  So something like:

### Results

```
b_id     |     item_desc         |    note
61             desc of item 61        text 2 for item b_id = 61
71             desc of item 71        text 3 for item b_id = 61
81             desc of item 81        text 1 for item b_id = 61
91             desc of item 91        text 2 for item b_id = 61
```

What I have tried:

```
select item_table.b_id, item_table.item_desc, 
from item_table, notes_bridge_table
where item_table.b_id = notes_bridge_table.b_id
and notes_bridge_table.a_id in
(select a_id from notes_table
 where notes_table.a_id = notes_bridge_table.a_id
 and notes_table.idxno, notes_table.a_id in
 (select max(idxno), a_id from notes_table group by a_id))
```

but the second to last line of "and notes_table.idxno, notes_table.a_id in" does not appear to be valid for sql server.

Comment: You are right -- Oracle allows the IN clause to have pairs of values but SQL Server only allows individuals. So the "where x, y in (select xx, yy from..." does not work. It has to be restructured.

Comment: remove the comma: `item_table.item_desc,<< from`

Comment: Gak! Old-style joins, really?

Comment: Just a little nitpick: the `(a,b) in (select x,y ...)` syntax is not specific to Oracle. It's defined by the SQL standard and supported by several DBMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why complicating? It can be simplified:

```
SELECT i.b_id, i.item_desc, n.note_text
FROM item_table AS i INNER JOIN notes_bridge_table AS b
ON i.b_id = b.b_id
INNER JOIN notes_table n ON b.a_id = n.a_id
INNER JOIN
(SELECT b_id, MAX(idxno) AS idxno
    FROM notes_table AS n INNER JOIN notes_bridge_table AS b
    ON n.a_id = b.a_id
    GROUP BY b.b_id) AS b2
ON b.b_id = b2.b_id AND b2.idxno = n.idxno
```

And... all complexity comes from completely redundant `a_id` column. Your table structure is not best.

Btw, column 3 doesn't show proper `b_id` in your example. This is correct output:

```
b_id   item_desc          note_text
------ ------------------ ---------------------------
61     desc of item 61    text 2 for item b_id = 61
71     desc of item 71    text 3 for item b_id = 71
81     desc of item 81    text 1 for item b_id = 81
91     desc of item 91    text 2 for item b_id = 91
```

Comment: Nenad - You are amazing!  Thank you so much!  I also do not like the structure but I was not here to vote when it became.  And thank you for knowing what I meant for the correct output!  Your help is truly amazing and I am very thankful!  I tried tons of ways of getting here and I'm confident I would not have except for your support.  Thank you!  Thank you so much for being a teacher.

Answer (score 2):

This query (in Oracle)

```
select * from t
where ( x, y ) in ( select x, y from t1 );
```

can be converted to a correlated subquery that runs on MS-SQL:

```
select * from t
where exists (
  select 1 from t1
  where t1.x = t.x and t1.y = t.y 
);
```

Here is a demo for Oracle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2300d/2

and for MS_SQL : http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2300d/2

Comment: Thank you!  I am keeping this one on file!  I sincerely appreciate the extra work to provide the demo!  It is much more clear to me now!  Thank you so much!